# Missing transaction

Tags: transactions, blockchain, lost-bitcoins, lost-transactions

I made a transfer on 6/16 from one wallet to another.  Despite verification on blockchain.com, the coin is gone from the sending wallet yet never arrived in the receiving wallet.  The receiving wallet address is valid until 6/23, and I am worried about what may happen if that horizon is crossed while the transaction is still missing.  Transaction info below.  Thanks in advance for any light anyone may be able to shed on this issue.

4bfc13e27bd2d4b22a7e8d2070b70059064913be89e0286e7c6c2ce146cadbef

smoothsus

Comment: How did you determine the payment did not arrive in the receiving wallet? Be as specific and detailed as you possibly can.

Comment: PGP Proof of Ownership of the receiving wallet:

Comment: -----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA256

This is a PGP signed proof of address 3LYiHuVePBSd7iVbpTFjgadGrvZB5xjRPk belongs to XXXXXXXXXX.  The address is valid as of 2019-06-16 09:23:54.  It received no funds and is guaranteed to be valid until 2019-06-23 09:23:54.
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----

Comment: Well, it received and then spent 0.0215682 BTC. You can see it on the blockchain.

Answer (score 2):

> the coin is gone from the sending wallet yet never arrived in the receiving wallet

This isn't really a thing - The transaction is confirmed, which means the coins did move. In fact, the `0.0215682` sent has already been spent (I am assuming that is the payment amount, as the other output goes to a p2pkh address, which seems likely for a change output), which means the receiving wallet not only picked up on the output, but also spent it.

> The receiving wallet address is valid until 6/23

Again, this is not really a thing - addresses remain valid indefinitely, although the receiving program may stop listening for transactions sent to it.

You should contact whoever operates the receiving wallet and ask them to rescan for transactions, no one else can help you. The transaction is complete as far as the Bitcoin blockchain is concerned, and any missing fund issues are due to an error/omission within the receiving wallet's code.

Comment: Well, it being spent that is news to me.  It was a newly created wallet with no transactions.  I am waiting on answers from support of the wallet operator, but have not heard anything back.  I will continue to monitor it and answers here.  Thank you for your assistance thus far.

Answer (score 1):

> **the coin is gone from the sending wallet yet never arrived in the receiving wallet.**

Although we often say (or write) that coins are stored in wallets, it is important to remember this is just a convenient shorthand analogy for communication between people.

In reality, Bitcoins don't exist in wallets, they are not stored in wallets and are not moved in and out of or between wallets. Bitcoins don't really travel between wallets and the dont really get sent by one wallet or arrive in another. That's all just handwaving and very loose analogy.

Furthermore, Bitcoins are not stored in the blockchain. The blockchain just keeps a list (a journal) of transactions involving amounts of money using Bitcoin as a unit of measure.

To summarize, whatever the blockchain says happened is what really happened. After about six confirmations it is very unlikely the blockchain will change it's view on this. If someones wallet disagrees with the general and established consensus view of the blockchain, the wallet is wrong. Possibly because the wallet is not [synchronized](https://bitcoin.org/en/faq#what-does-synchronizing-mean-and-why-does-it-take-so-long). In theory it may be the receiving-address was wrongly entered - but this is relatively unlikely.

Lets say you went into a shop and took a $20 banknote out of your wallet and handed it to the shopkeeper who put it into his wallet. Then the shopkeeper denies receiving your $20. What do you do then? If you are lucky there is a witness. The witness can't resolve your dispute, you have to take that to a court of law and ask the witness to testify.

The blockchain is simply your witness. The blockchain can produce evidence but it can't resolve a dispute.

---

> **the transaction is still missing.**

If it is in the blockchain it isn't missing.

If it isn't in the blockchain, you still have the money.

Your transaction is [in the blockchain](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/4bfc13e27bd2d4b22a7e8d2070b70059064913be89e0286e7c6c2ce146cadbef) and, at time of writing, has 328 confirmations. 6 confirmations is usually taken as certain. It is as certain as it is possible to be. It is definitely not missing. Waiting will not make it significantly more concrete, more visible or more indisputable. There is no chance of it disappearing (short of unprecedented disaster and the possible end of the Bitcoin world)

Comment: I am hoping that it is just a wallet synchronization issue.  Still nothing though, so my hope in that being the case is dwindling.